# how to use IN operator in oracle apex classic report

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

i want use in operator in oracle apex classic report for sorting details data and also multiple details data. so how can i do that by sql query?
please help me.

```
SELECT fr_st_invoiceno,
      sales_type,
      cust_id,
      sia_id,
      coll_amount,
      remarks,
      cash_bank,
      bank_name,
      check_no,
      update_id,
      updatedate,
      slno,
      invoice_type,
      trcode,
      send_voucher_no,
      send_voucher_no_depot
FROM dis_invoice_tk_collection
WHERE position = 1
      AND   fromstore_id =:p157_depot
      AND   send_voucher_no IN (:p157_send_voucher_no)
```

Thanks & best regard.
morshed.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What problems do you have when using IN? It works in a classic report as anywhere else. If you want to sort data, user ORDER BY (what does IN have to do with it?). What is "multiple details data"? Could you provide some more info, create a test case, attach a screenshot ... anything?

Comment: i want to use this code in classic report:

select FR_ST_INVOICENO,      
       SALES_TYPE,
       CUST_ID,
       SIA_ID,
       COLL_AMOUNT,
       REMARKS,
       CASH_BANK,
       BANK_NAME,
       CHECK_NO,
       UPDATE_ID,
       UPDATEDATE,
       SLNO,
       INVOICE_TYPE,
       TRCODE,
       SEND_VOUCHER_NO,
       SEND_VOUCHER_NO_DEPOT
  from DIS_INVOICE_TK_COLLECTION
  where POSITION=1
  and FROMSTORE_ID =:P157_DEPOT
  and SEND_VOUCHER_NO in (:P157_SEND_VOUCHER_NO)

but i can't...

Answer (score 0):

You have to split a comma-separated values into rows, such as

```
and send_voucher in
  (select regexp_substr(:P157_SEND_VOUCHER_NO, '[^,]+', 1, level)
   from dual
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:P157_SEND_VOUCHER_NO, ',') + 1
  )
```

presuming that P157_SEND_VOUCHER_NO looks like `10,20,30`.

Don't forget to put P157_SEND_VOUCHER_NO item into "page items to submit" property.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND   instr(','||:p157_send_voucher_no||',', ','||send_voucher_no||',') > 0
```